# Grouping with LINQ to XML. Creating xls subtotals

Tags: linq-to-xml, xls

I´m trying to get an xls file with this format, the red rows for Totals.

[image]

I get the detail using XDocument and with the next code in XElement("Worksheet",...)

```
from item in lista
select
(new XElement("Row",new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.project)),
                    new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.type)),
                    new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.subtype)),
                    new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "Number"), item.ppto)),
                    new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "Number"), item.amount))
            )
)
```

How can I get the nodes for the totals grouping by Project, Type and Subtype?

Regards

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're tying to do. Are you creating an xls file from XML or the other way around? Where did `lista` come from in your code example? Maybe you could give a little more of the code you've tried and what the XML looks like.

Answer (score 0):

here I post my XML code with detail. In the code you can see where **lista** come from.
The goal is an XML file ready to be opened with Excel. The code run well, but I´ll need to add subtotals (the red lines in the image)
Regards, María

```
namespace reportsToXLS
{
    public partial class myMvtos : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnExportDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = null;
            OleDbCommand cm = null;
            OleDbDataReader dr = null;

            string sql = " SELECT project,type,subtype,ppto,amount from table_mvtos"; 

            List<Movimiento> lstMovimientos = new List<Movimiento>();

            con = Conexion.Obtain("myConection");

            con.Open();
            cm = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            cm.CommandTimeout = 240;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Movimiento mov = new Movimiento();
                mov.project = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("project")) ? "" :  dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("project"));
                mov.type = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("type"));
                mov.subtype = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("subtype")) ? "" : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("subtype")).Trim();
                mov.ppto = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("ppto"))?0: Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("ppto")));
                mov.amount = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("amount")) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("amount")));

                lstMovimientos.Add(mov);

            }

            leerDatos(lstMovimientos);
        }


        protected void leerDatos(List<Movimiento> lista)
        {
            string nombreFichero;
            string ruta;

            try
            {
                XNamespace aw = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                XNamespace o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office";
                XNamespace x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
                XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";

                XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                   new XElement("Workbook",
                      new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
                      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"),
                      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
                      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
                      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"),
                      new XElement("DocumentProperties", new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn=schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
                                                         new XElement("Author", "María Pedreira"),
                                                         new XElement("Created", DateTime.Today),
                                                         new XElement("Company", "Coremain SLU")
                                  ),
                      new XElement("ExcelWorkBook",
                                    new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn=schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
                                    new XElement("WindowHeight", "16795"),
                                    new XElement("WindowWidth", "8460"),
                                    new XElement("WindowTopX", "120"),
                                    new XElement("WindowTopY", "15"),
                                    new XElement("ProtectStructure", "False"),
                                    new XElement("ProtectWindows", "False")
                                  ),
                      new XElement("Styles", new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "Default"), new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "Normal"),
                                                            new XElement("Alignment", "", new XAttribute(ss + "Vertical", "Bottom")),
                                                            new XElement("Borders", ""),
                                                            new XElement("Font", ""),
                                                            new XElement("Interior", ""),
                                                            new XElement("NumberFormat", ""),
                                                            new XElement("Protection", "")
                                                         ),
                                            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "s21"), new XElement("Font", "", new XAttribute(x + "Family", "Swiss"), new XAttribute(ss + "Bold", "1")))
                                  ),
                      new XElement("Worksheet",
                                    new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "Sheet1"),
                                    new XElement("Table",
                                                          new XElement("Row",  new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "PROJECT")),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "TYPE")),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "SUBTYPE")),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "PPTO")),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "AMOUNT"))
                                                                        ),
                                                            from item in lista
                                                            select
                                                            new XElement("Row", new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.project)),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.type)),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "Number"), item.ppto)),
                                                                                new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "Number"), item.amount))
                                                                        )
                                                 ),
                                    new XElement("WorksheetOptions",
                                                          new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn=schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
                                                          new XElement("Print", new XElement("ValidPrinterInfo", ""),
                                                                                                        new XElement("HorizontalResolution", "600"),
                                                                                                        new XElement("VerticalResolution", "600")),
                                                                                 new XElement("Selected", ""),
                                                                                 new XElement("Panes", new XElement("Pane", new XElement("Number", "3"),
                                                                                                                            new XElement("ActiveRow", "5"),
                                                                                                                            new XElement("ActiveCol", "1"))),
                                                                                 new XElement("ProtectObjects", "False"), new XElement("ProtectScenarios", "False")
                                               )
                                )
                  )
                );

                nombreFichero = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_prueba.xls";
                ruta = @"C:\" + nombreFichero;
                xdoc.Save(ruta);

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(ruta);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreFichero);
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
                    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class Movimiento
    {
        private int anho;
        private string project;
        private string type;
        private string subtype;
        private double ppto;
        private double amount;

        public int Anho
        { get { return anho; } set { anho = value; } }
        public string  Project
        { get { return project; } set { project = value; } }
        public string Type
        { get { return type; } set { type = value; } }
        public int Subtype
        { get { return subtype; } set { subtype = value; } }
        public double Ppto
        { get { return ppto; } set { ppto=value; } }
        public double Amount
        { get { return amount; } set {  amount=value; } }

    }
}
```

Comment: This should have been added as an edit to the question instead of posted as an answer